# The largest possible prime gap?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

What is the largest possible [prime gap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Conjectures_about_gaps_between_primes) if we observe only 1000-digits numbers? There are few conjectures about this question but is there something that we can say and be absolutely sure of it?

Comment: You're talking about a particular finite interval of numbers. Results and conjectures on prime gaps generally come in the form of either asymptotic growth or densities, so for particulars you either go for a probabilistic idea using heuristics or you crunch everything though a computer given enough time, resources, and power. (Also, you didn't specify binary versus decimal base.)

Comment: Well, by [Bertrand’s postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) it must be less than $5\times 10^{999}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $a=A(n)$ is the $n^{th}$ primorial (that is, the product of the first n primes), then at least $a,a\pm2, a\pm3,... a\pm p_n,a\pm (p_n+1)$ are composite, giving a prime gap of length at least $p_n-1$.  At $n=350, p_n=2357$, the primorial $a=A(n)$ has 1000 digits (its base 10 logarithm is about 999.375).  Actually, with Pari/GP it's easy to verify that $a-4152 ... a+3312$ are composite and 
$a-4153$ and $a+3313$ apparently are prime, giving a prime gap of length 7465.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) gives a result of R. Rankin, that (where $g(p)$ denotes the gap after $p$) $g(p) > 2e^\gamma (\ln p) (\ln \ln p)  (\ln \ln \ln \ln p)/(\ln \ln \ln p)^3$ infinitely often.  For $p\approx 10^{1000}$, that expression evaluates to about 5300.  The article also gives a conjectured bound of H. Cramér, that $g(p) = O((\ln p)^2)$, which for 1000-digit numbers would be some multiple of 5 million.

For a broader discussion with numerous references, see the [Prime Gaps](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeGaps.html) page at wolfram.com.
For more-recent results on lower bounds for maximal prime gaps, see the arXiv.org paper or preprint *[Long gaps between primes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5029)* by Ford, Green, Konyagin, Maynard, and Tao, and see Tao's commentary at [terrytao.wordpress](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/08/21/large-gaps-between-consecutive-prime-numbers/), and see [additional results / background](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/prime-gaps/) at the same site.

Comment: H. Maier (1985) shows that the expected coefficient of Cramér's asymptotic is $2/e^\gamma\approx1.123,$ so that would suggest 5.95 million.  M. Wolf suggests that a closer asymptotic should be W(p)^2, so using the same constant you'd get 5.91 million.  Of course both are looking at the largest prime gap up to that point, not restricted to 1000-digit ones, so maybe you'd want to be a smidge smaller.  I'd need to play around with probabilistic models a bit to find out roughly how much.  So in any case 5 million seems like the right neighborhood.

Comment: @Charles:  I believe Andrew Granville proposed that the constant was $2/e^\gamma$.  Based on looking at the papers, this is what I made out.  Also see (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture#Cram.C3.A9r-Granville_conjecture)

Comment: @Eric Naslund: Granville certainly did suggest that; I thought the number originated with Maier but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Why is $a-1$ necessarily a composite number @ jwpat7

Comment: @BradGraham, it isn't (eg 2*3*5-1 = 29) so I have edited to correct that error. Thanks.