# How one can show that this inequality holds true for infinitely many primes

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $(g_{k})_{k≥1}$ be the sequence of primes gap. In 1938, Robert Rankin proved the existence of a constant $c > 0$ such that the inequality:

$$g_{k}>c×(log k×loglog k×logloglog k)/((logloglog k)²).....(*)$$  holds for infinitely many values $k$, improving the results of Westzynthius and Paul Erdős (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Lower_bounds). He later showed that one can take any constant $0<c < e^{γ}$, where $γ$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

My **question** is: How one can show that inequality $(*)$ holds true for infinitely many primes.

Comment: Wikipedia cites a [paper by Ford et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5029) that gives a proof of even stronger claim with arbitrary $c$.

Comment: @Conifold: I am interested only if any inequality is satisfied by primes.

Comment: You mean when $k$ is a prime? If it is satisfied for all $k$ then for primes in particular.

Comment: @Conifold:  it is not satisfied by all integers. Only holds for infinitely many values $k$.

Comment: There is a relevant post which mentioned a few resources (including a arXiv paper showing the proof) you might be interested: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65237/the-largest-possible-prime-gap (found by [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=prime%2C%20gap%2C%20%24g(p)%20%3E%202e%5E%5Cgamma%20(%5Cln%20p)%20(%5Cln%20%5Cln%20p)%20%20(%5Cln%20%5Cln%20%5Cln%20%5Cln%20p)%2F(%5Cln%20%5Cln%20%5Cln%20p)%5E3%24&p=1))

Comment: @WeiZhong: They only uses $p$ instead of $k$.

Comment: @Helena Sorry it is not helpful. It seems relevant to me.